# classic ASP, relative vs absolute path

Tags: asp-classic, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm having trouble figuring out relative vs absolute path in classic ASP.

In IIS 7.5 I created a website that points to c:/inetpub/wwwroot/websitename.
In that website I have a page that displays the links to some mp4's videos.They are located in c:/inetpub/wwwroot/websitename/DVD.

Those links point to localhost/websitename/DVD/videoname.mp4

In some computers clicking in one those videos it gives me an error.Basically, it says that the file does not exist in c:/inetpub/wwwroot/websitename/websitename/dvd/videoname.mp4

How would handle this problem.
(I hope is clear enough)
Tanks!

Comment: **Those links point to localhost/websitename/DVD/videoname.mp4**

it should point to `localhost/DVD/videoname.mp4`. you `localhost` is `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/websitename`

Comment: So now I got a variable that holds the value of Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME"), which is localhost\DVD. I got the message "Path not found".

Answer (score 0):

Simply use such path:

```
<a href="DVD/videoname.mp4">videoname</a>
```

This way you don't have to mess with localhost or websitename in the links, it will just look for folder named "DVD" in the same place as the file with the link and take the files from there.